# Stop multiple file GCC compilation when one of them fails

Tags: c, bash, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors

I have created the following bash build script file :

```
BLD_INCLUDE="-I..source/module1 -I..source/module2"
SRC_MOD1="$(find ../source/module1 -name '*.c')"
SRC_MOD2="$(find ../source/module2 -name '*.c')"
BLD_SOURCES="../source/program.c $SRC_MOD1 $SRC_MOD2"
BLD_LINKER="" #if there is any need of linker - irrelevant here
gcc $BLD_FLAGS $BLD_INCLUDE -o outputobject $BLD_SOURCES $BLD_LINKER
```

I am building like this because there are lot of files I need to compile.

The problem is, when executing multiple files using gcc, like above, if the compilation of one of the files fails, it prompts for the error along with "compilation terminated" and then continues executing other files.

The behaviour I want is, that even if one of the file fails to compile, whole compilation stops.

That is, in my case : suppose there is a header file missing. Now gcc tries to compile the very first `.c` , finds that the header file is missing, prompts

> fatal error : file missing error
>   compilation terminated.

and then continues with execution of other `.c` files. Since the header file is missing in all, it keeps on giving me this error and continues execution.

I want this build script to terminate as soon as compilation fails even of one of the files.

Edit : Not a duplicate of [Stop GCC on error with multiple files compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187780/stop-gcc-on-error-with-multiple-files-compilation/41189203#41189203), it originated from this very question itself (read comments). The question even refers back to this.

Comment: Well since you are writing a bash script you could loop over all files and first compile each source file with the gccs `-c` option which would result in an object file .o extension for each source and if that fails abort. However for bigger project a Makefile would be much better.

Comment: Stop using batch file and use make (whatever version of it Cmake, GNU make, BSD make, etc.)

Comment: @Inian I am not sure. I did not use any tool. I remember seeing similar script in some project, I merely adapt it to build mine.

I execute it by invoking ```./build``` and it works just fine if everything is present.

Comment: @SaurabhShrivastava: Can you output `BLD_FLAGS` variable as `echo $BLD_FLAGS` ?

Comment: @hetepeperfan I want all of them to get incorporated into a single output file, here ```outputobject``` and yes I have made a makefile too, just trying to fix this.

Comment: @Inian sorry there is line missing here, $BLD_FLAGS contains parameters I pass to GCC, like -Werror etc..

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, I have a make file too, just trying to fix this.

Comment: @SaurabhShrivastava: Did you refer my answer at all? add `-Wfatal-errors` also to the  `BLD_FLAGS` variable and export it and run the build again.

Comment: @Inian I have already tried it. As explained to the comment in your answer, it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the way you are retrieving sources files name. Probably there are newline in the output of find command that make the behavior weird.

Comment: @LPs Probably. I am all open for suggestions. How do I improve this?

Comment: Could you try using `SRC_MOD1="$(find ../source/module1 -name '*.c' -printf '%p ')"` and `SRC_MOD2="$(find ../source/module2 -name '*.c' -printf '%p ')"` and enabling `-Wfatal-errors`

Comment: @LPs  Okay I think I understand what you are trying to do. Here's what happened.

It threw errors that ```'%p``` and ```'``` are not a valid directory. 

So. I removed the space between them and it spit out all the directory concatenated, which ,_again_, formed an invalid directory.

So, I guess, the ```space in '%p '``` was intentional to separate the addresses using a space instead of newline.

Comment: Well problem can be the script because `find -name '*.c' -printf "%p "` works fine in terminal

Comment: @LPs What do you suggest? Is there any other way to _correct_ this build script. I already have a make file but i want to fix this.

Comment: I guess looping through files will be the best way, @hetepeperfan would you please write an answer regarding that?

Comment: @SaurabhShrivastava: `-Wfatal-errors` flag does't help you in any way? do you think it is ok to remove it?

Comment: @Inian Sadly,currently it doesn't. Because maybe as @LPs said, find might be returning paths with an endline, converting it into multiple gcc commands. ```-Wfatal-errors``` only ends the current command.

Comment: Ok, I'm back. I tryed an sh script with `#!/bin/sh
TEST="$(find . -name '*.c' -printf '%p ')"
echo $TEST` and it works well. It outputs only files names without newlines. Could you post your whole script to check if there are some differences?

Comment: @LPs I tried it. This is how it went : with or without ```-printf '%p '``` , both ways, the file paths are stored with a space (I checked ASCII value, came 32 for both), not newline. SO, we are back to square 1.

Comment: So.....I don't know how to help you: `-Wfatal-errors` should work. What is your gcc version?

Comment: @LPs 4.9.2. I am on Ubuntu if it helps..

Comment: I tested it on my platform. It seems that `-Wfatal-errors` and `-fmax-errors` work on a single compilation units, so cannot be used for what you want to do.

Comment: I posted [a new summed-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187780/stop-gcc-on-error-with-multiple-files-compilation/41189203#41189203) about it. Take a look at answers. I'm afraid makefile is the only way to do so.

Comment: write the script with a loop, each iteration through the loop to perform a single compile.  Check the returned code/value from each call to `gcc` and exit the loop if that value is not 0.  To implement the loop, you might want to use the `foreach` function.

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, doing that for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop GCC on error with multiple files compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187780/stop-gcc-on-error-with-multiple-files-compilation)

Comment: @Armali Not a duplicate, it originated from this very question itself (read comments). The question you pointed even refers back to this question.

Comment: @Saurabh Shrivastava - I don't share your opinion that the other question were _Not a duplicate_. That it _refers back to this question_ is irrelevant. After all, the other question has an accepted answer that also applies to the question here, like it or not.